# How can I use Phonegap and the fixed divs when use setTimeout or animation css3?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, cordova

When i put fixed div in the top and use SetTimeout or animation with css3, the div changes his position.

When scroll the div changes position and goes down or up depends where direction scroll.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script>
    cargart();
function cargart(){
    setTimeout("cargart()",1000);
    document.getElementById("tmap").innerHTML= new Date();
}
</script>
<style>
    #menuindex2{
        position:fixed;
        background-color: #111111;
        width:100%;
        height:52px;
    }
    #tmap{
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:55px;

    }

</style>
</head>


<body >
<div id="menuindex2">
    div fixed
</div>

<div id="tmap">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For android, in your main file, set the window type to "SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE"

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 1000*60*60*24*7);
    //getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
}
```

This will make it so the webview resizes when the keyboard is shown and your header will still be fixed at the top of the screen.  The same can be done for ios in the config.xml settings.